# How to implement track/following algorythm in ROS?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Im working on a new porject in ROS, which consist of controlling an USV robot (unmanned surface vehicle). The things is I have the simulating model provided by Heron (https://packages.clearpathrobotics.com/stable/images/latest/melodic-bionic/amd64/), but what I want to do is implement the most simple planner and path following tracker to see if it really works. Im quite new using ROS, so I don't know where to start, if there is any example or code provided. I've already investigated, and I've seen the Pure Pursuit could be easy to apply, but again, I dont know how. I am aware that it is a huge question and really hard to explain everything but I would really appreciate if someone could help me.
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393405/how-to-implement-track/following-algorythm-in-ros?/) by [LuisCa](https://answers.ros.org/users/92274/luisca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @LuisCa

I'd start first with the Clearpath Robotics tutorials found here: https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/melodic/heron/additional_sim_worlds.html

In the example, `inspection simulation`:

`roslaunch cpr_inspection_gazebo inspection_world.launch platform:=heron`

the USV performs inspection and navigation tasks. You can further see how is done in the repo:
https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/cpr_gazebo/tree/melodic-devel/cpr_inspection_gazebo and
https://github.com/orgs/heron/repositories

Specific for navigation take a look at this:
https://github.com/heron/heron_simulator/blob/kinetic-devel/heron_gazebo/launch/spawn_heron.launch

```
<!-- Translate Twist message from twist_server to Wrench message -->
<node pkg="heron_gazebo" type="twist_translate" name="twist_translate">
         <rosparam file="$(find heron_gazebo)/config/heron_controller.yaml" />
   <param name="cov_limits/velocity" value="0.01" />
</node>

<!-- Translates navsat/velocity from Vector3Stamped to TwistStamped on navsat/vel -->
<node pkg="heron_gazebo" type="navsat_vel_translate" name="navvel_translate" />

<node pkg="heron_gazebo" type="activate_control_service" name="activate_control_service" />
```

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1